# how to set the interval of points on Y - Axis highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am using highcharts for the first time, and I am trying to figure out how to set the Y axis points static.

I have used min=0 and max=140 , and the points on y axis come up as 0,25,50,75,100,125 and 150. Wherein I want it as 0,20,40,60,80,100,140.

Can someone let me know how could I achieve this.

Below is the highchart optins :

```
 var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'Div1',
            width: 600,
            height: 400

        },
        yAxis:{
            min: 0, max: 140,

            lineColor: '#FF0000',
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'

        },
        plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 10,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Value',
            data: YaxisValuesArray
        }]
    });

});
```

[image: Points on X axis]

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can set the tickInterval (http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#yAxis.tickInterval) on the axis
http://jsfiddle.net/blaird/KdHME/

```
$(function () {
    var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'Div1',
            width: 600,
            height: 400

        },

        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },


        title: {
            text: 'Productivity Report',

            x: -20 //center
        },

        xAxis: {
            lineColor: '#FF0000',
            categories: [1, 2, 3]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 140,
            tickInterval: 20,
            lineColor: '#FF0000',
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: 'Values'

            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 10,
                color: '#808080'
            }]
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ''
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            borderWidth: 0
        },


        series: [{
            name: 'Value',
            data: [
                [1, 10],
                [2, 20],
                [3, 30]
            ]
        }]
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! You saved my day, I was using tickinterval earlier. But it was not working ...And now I notice I was using tickinterval instead of tickInterval(case sensitive) :D

Comment: I have another question for you how do I add "%" symbol next to the Y axis points like 20%,40%,60% etc..

Comment: Use the labels format: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/labels-format/  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.labels.format

Comment: Thank You Barbara I got it !

Comment: I did not want to post it as another question, I am tring to markers set on the x axis. Did not find a property under the API to achieve this. Could you please let me know how can I do it. I am attaching a picture. Blue points on x axis is what I am trying to get

Comment: Sorry Janet, other than faking it with a series that is all zeros, I don't think you can do that.  As far as I know, there isn't a way to change the axis ticks to markers.  You might want to ask it as another question, because someone else might know.

Comment: Thank you for your response Barbara. Appreciate it. Sure, will post it as another question.

Answer (score 3):

To do this using HighChart in a [StockChart](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo) mode, I just need to set the property tickPixelInterval.

```
yAxis: {
            ...
            tickPixelInterval: 35
            ...
        }
```