# how to set the interval of points if I have 2 Y axes

Tags: highcharts

I have tried setting using tickinterval as stated in this [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19547933/how-to-set-the-interval-of-points-on-y-axis-highcharts)

but unable to set it.

https://jsfiddle.net/diasraphael88/L8waqonp/

In the primary axis I m trying to set the below code

```
min: 0,
max: 100,
tickInterval: 10,
```

In the secondary axis I am trying to set the below code

```
min: 0,
max: 5,
tickInterval: .5,
```

**Note:** when I am using one axis the value is setting properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `alignTicks` option:

```
chart: {
    alignTicks: false,
    ...
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b0c4g52f/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.alignTicks